# Chromium has hard-to-see tab color scheme

Tags: debian, chrome

I recently ran `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get update`. Chromium was updated. But when I open new tabs, the other tabs are dark, so I can't read their titles.

[image]

The non-Google tab in the upper left is Unix Stack Exchange, but the title is barely visible. How do I make the tab titles visible again?

I'm running Chromium 69.0.3497.92 on Debian 9.5.

Comment: Do previous versions have the same issue? or is it new?

Comment: @mattia.b89 I don’t remember what version I had before the update. But it didn’t have this problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chromium settings (click on the three vertical dots) At the section Appearance try switching The Theme to Classic.

Also you can try running Chromium with the terminal :

```
chromium --disable-extensions --disable-plugins
```

or

```
chromium-browser --disable-extensions --disable-plugins
```